# What is an event on a lower level?

Tags: c#, windows, event-handling

Suppose there is a simple window containing a single button created in a high level language such as C#. This button has an onClick event with an associated handler. What happens behind the scenes once this is compiled? Does it, on a basic level, produce a windows message loop that calls a GetMessage function, decodes and reads it, and then handles/re routes it? Similar to the following MFC example?

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0) { 
  if (bRet == -1) { 
    // handle the error and possibly exit 
  } 
  else {          
    TranslateMessage(&msg); 
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
  } 
}
```

Are all events for a windows GUI just a decoded and modified version of the WM_ style messages?

**Edit:**
Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to understand it an OS kind of level.

Comment: No, events in C# do not make use of window messages. Rather, they use delegates and are part of the language. Fairly broad to answer here; I suggest a book on programming in C#. There are lots of good ones available.

Comment: To add to what Cody wrote, they are little more than `MulticastDelegate` (and note that in .NET for various reasons all the `Delegate` are `MulticastDelegate`) plus some multithread checking... If you look at the IL code you'll see that they don't do very much underneath: http://goo.gl/WM4rKG

Comment: I disagree with Cody's answer.  The delegate has to be able to handle both windows events and c# events.  The local C# events are handled exclusively within c# and don't use messaging, but delegates can also handle windows events.

Comment: Broadly speaking, events are collections *(of sorts)* of delegates. When you invoke an event, you invoke all delegates in the collection. I could try to answer it in CLR terms, but I'm afraid I'll get some part wrong. Better wait for Jon Skeet / Eric Lippert to come along! :-)

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray and xanatos. What I'm trying to understand, is what happens at a lower level than this, at the operating system level. My goal is to get a better understanding of how embedded systems implement events and interprocess communication. I'll do some more searching (the terms 'embedded events' list lots of conference related things), but any more ideas would be great. I like the site you posted.

Comment: @mattb5906 .NET events are very high level events. WM_ events are a totally different beast. The WinForms API uses .NET events to "map" WM_ events, but it does it event by event. There is no magic trick to do it. Microsoft programmers made a big `switch` (as showed by Brackett, but he used an `if`) and, based on the WM_ message, activate one .NET event or another. No magic, only boring programming.

Comment: @xanatos - You're right, a switch is more canonical - I just used an if because that's what it decompiled to. Replaced w/reference source.

Comment: I'll add that there is a little optimization in the `Control` class: there is a single "collection" for the subscribed events. In this way non-subscribed events don't waste memory (normally you would need tens of events, so tens of references, for each control... Events that are very rarely subscribed. It would be a waste). It is the `EventHandlerList Events`, where  `EventHandlerList` is like a `List<Delegate>`

Comment: Thanks all. I see that a delegate is comparable to a type safe function pointer (c++), so that all makes sense to me now. I didn't think how much of a higher level C# is when compared to C or C++, which lead to my badly worded question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two parts to this question - how does a CLR (aka C#) event compare to a Windows message, and how does a `Button` implement a CLR event.

On the one hand - yes, a `Button`'s `Click` event is a [wrapper over the message loop and `WM_` messages](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case NativeMethods.WM_REFLECT + NativeMethods.WM_COMMAND:
                if (NativeMethods.Util.HIWORD(m.WParam) == NativeMethods.BN_CLICKED) {
                    Debug.Assert(!GetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint), "Shouldn't get BN_CLICKED when UserPaint");
                    if (!ValidationCancelled) {
                        OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
                    }                        
                }
                break;
            case NativeMethods.WM_ERASEBKGND:
                DefWndProc(ref m);
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, a CLR event has nothing to do with message loops and WM_ messages - it only appears to because you're looking at it in context of WinForms, which chooses to expose WM messages as C# events.

A C# event is nothing more than a callback routine - you register a callback, and the implementing class calls it when something interesting happens.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think I get what you are saying. A CLR event if more generic and hence not comparable? If you went far enough down, would all of the user interaction 'events', like mouse clicked, come back to the windows message queues at an OS level? Or is this is handled some other way?

Comment: @mattb5906 - yes, in Windows (and most other mainstream, graphical OS's) a message loop is how they dispatch input events. Conceivably, you could have an OS that used polling and blocking instead (which is how we normally write command line apps) - but I don't know of one that uses that paradigm for GUI apps.